# Unexpected $end but I don't know why PHP

Tags: php, html, authentication

I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/a1633717/public_html/members.php on line 59`
 When I checked the code, I couldn't find any error. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$nuser=$_SESSION['user'];
$auser=$_SESSION['admin'];

if($nuser){  
    $userfinal=$nuser;    
} elseif($auser) {    
    $userfinal=$auser;
}

if(isset($userfinal)) {
    $Members = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM characters WHERE level ='1' ORDER BY exp
    DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    $numRowsMembers = mysql_num_rows($Members);
?>

<table border="0">

<?php
for($count = 1; $count <= $numRowsMembers; $count++)
{
    $name = mysql_fetch_array($Members);
?>

<tr>

<?php
    echo '<td><a href="member_profile.php?username=' . $name['user'] . '">' . name['user'] . '</a></td>';
?>

</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

The error is at the bottom, and when I looked at it I did't see an error. How can I fix that? I changed the order of  and the php but nothing. Thanks in advance

Comment: What prevented you from indenting your code? And from debugging the problem by stripping away bits of code until you end up with a 4-5 line testcase and, probably, the answer? And why the double line breaks?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation; it's tricky to read....

Comment: Wheres the closing } for your if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means you forgot to close a bracket, in this case, you forgot to close the if: `if(isset($userfinal)){`

Just add another closure bracket where you need it (probably after the last closure bracket so:

```
</tr>

<?php

}

?>

</table>

<?php

} // Closure of the if

?>
```

Comment: ... which will render the HTML invalid.

Comment: Very, very misleading to use the term "closure" here.

Answer (score 9):

Simple.

Count your `{`, then count your `}`. They do not match.

Writing code with proper indentation would have made this very evident to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if(isset($userfinal))` is not closed. You need to close that if loop.

Answer (score 0):

You never close:

```
if(isset($userfinal)){
```

I take it you want this at the end of your file:

```
    <?php

}

?>

</table>

<?php

}

?>
```

Here's your code all fixed up:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

$nuser = $_SESSION['user'];
$auser = $_SESSION['admin'];

if($nuser) {
    $userfinal = $nuser;
} elseif($auser) {
    $userfinal = $auser;
}

if(isset($userfinal)) {
    $Members = mysql_query("SELECT user FROM characters WHERE level ='1' ORDER BY exp DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    $numRowsMembers = mysql_num_rows($Members);
?>

<table border="0">
    <?php
    for($count = 1; $count <= $numRowsMembers; $count++) {
        $name = mysql_fetch_array($Members);
    ?>

    <tr>
        <?php
        echo '<td><a href="member_profile.php?username=' . $name['user'] . '">' . $name['user'] . '</a></td>';
        ?>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

Indenting and spacing properly would help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to close the `if` block.